# use oracle JMC along with other javaagent like aspectj

Tags: aspectj, jmc

I'm trying to profile my application with JDK bundled JMC flight recorder

However, when I apply below JVM args to enable recorder:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
```

All of my aop advice seems not work, looks like the agent does not take effect:

```
-javaagent:.......\aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar
```

I'm wondering if `-XX:+FlightRecorder` has its own class instrument/enhancement, which has conflict with others like aspectj weaver?

Answer (score 0):

It's already fixed after 1.7.4:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415266

Comment: In order to close this question, please accept your own answer if you think it is correct.